# C++: Estrutura de dados / Fila

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados, fila

Fiz um algorítimo de estrutura de dados. Coloquei todo meu conhecimento nele. Não estou conseguindo achar o erro. Deixo o enunciado do exercício abaixo:

> Faça um programa que crie duas filas F1 e F2, de tamanho 10, cada.
>   Leia 20 números inteiros e, se o número lido for par, insira-o na fila
>   F1 e, se for ímpar, na fila F2. Na sequência, caso o número lido seja
>   múltiplo de 3, retirar um elemento da fila F1, armazenando-o em uma
>   variável auxiliar e, depois, escreva-o no vídeo e insira-o na fila F2.
>   Caso o número lido seja múltiplo de 5, retirar um elemento da fila F2,
>   armazenando-o em uma variável auxiliar e, depois, escreva-o no vídeo e
>   insira-o na fila F1. Um número pode ser tanto múltiplo de 3 quanto de
>   5 e, neste caso, apresente uma mensagem no vídeo e não faça nada nas
>   filas, passando para a leitura do próximo número. Pare de ler quando
>   já tiverem sido lidos os 20 números ou quando ocorrer overflow ou
>   underflow em alguma fila.

```
int main()
{
    int f=-1, r=-1, f1[10], f2[10], cont=0, val=0, aux=0, tam=9;

do{
    cout << "Informe um valor: " << endl;
        cin >> val;
    cout << " " << endl;

    if(val%2==0){
            if(r==tam){
                cout << "OVERFLOW!" << endl << endl;
                    return 0;
            }else{
                f1[++r]=val;
            }
    }else{
        if(r==tam){
            cout << "OVERFLOW!" << endl << endl;
                return 0;
        }else{
                f2[++r]=val;
        }
    }

    if(val%3==0){
            if(r==f){
                cout << "UNDERFLOW!" << endl << endl;
                    return 0;
            }else{
            aux=f1[f+1];
            f++;
            if(f==r){
                f=r=-1;
            cout << "Valor retirado: " << aux << endl << endl;
            f2[++r]=aux;
            }
            }
    }

    if(val%5==0){
            if(r==f){
                cout << "UNDERFLOW!" << endl << endl;
                    return 0;
            }else{
            aux=f2[f+1];
            f++;
            if(f==r){
                f=r=-1;
            cout << "Valor retirado: " << aux << endl << endl;
            f1[++r]=aux;
            }
            }
    }

    if(val%3==0 && val%5==0){
        cout << "Numero mulitplo de 3 e 5!" << endl << endl;
    }

cont++;
}while(cont < 20);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro que apresenta ?

Comment: Não estou conseguindo escrever as filas. E o resultado não é esperado

Comment: Esse enunciado é um pouco estranho no minimo. Porque se inserir o número 3 teoricamente está a acertar em 2 casos, o ser impar e ser múltiplo de 3, o que removia um elemento do `F1` para o `F2` e inseria outro para `F2`. Isso também implica que não pode começar com um número impar caso contrario não tem nada para remover de `F1`

Comment: Pois é. Não consegui entender muito bem também!

Comment: E a mesma coisa acontece para um múltiplo de 5 que há de ser impar caso acabe em `5` ou par caso acabe em `10`. Aconselho a tentar rever o enunciado com o professor para clarificar o objetivo do trabalho e de como é suposto funcionar.

Comment: Vou falar com ele. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para começar, se é um exercício de estruturas de dados então é esperado que se crie um tipo estrutura de fila. Por exemplo,

```
// Tipo estrutura de fila
struct Queue {
    int iStt ;        // Índice de início
    int iEnd ;        // Índice de fim
    int elems[10] ;   // Elementos na fila
} ;
```

é suficiente para estruturar. Com isso, você pode definir localmente as variáveis filas `Fila F1;` e `Fila F2;` para representar as duas filas. Em C++, pode também criar métodos para a estrutura, possibilitando fácil inicialização, armazenamento, acesso, retirada, etc. Se não for permitido, ao menos deve ter o direito de criar funções que inicializam, acessam e alteram as filas.

Pelo que vi no seu código, o índice usado para indicar posição da fila F1 é usado para indicar o da fila F2 também, o que está errado. Cada fila tem que ter seu índice de início e também seu índice de fim. Só de criar um tipo estrutura de fila, esse problema já é resolvido.

Também recomendo usar nomenclaturas mais intuitivas (por exemplo, é bom índices usarem a letra "i", contadores usarem a letra "c", números temporários usarem "t", coisas assim) e indentação adequada (manter o nível do escopo), ambas medidas visando legibilidade. Muitos professores cobram fortemente esse tipo de coisa.

Alguma dúvida?

Comment: Muito obrigado! Me ajudou bastante!